# Ribbon picture of single strand with a knot

Tags: general-topology, knot-theory, knot-invariants

I was reading Steven Simon's [notes](http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/SteveSimon/topological2016/TopoBook.pdf) on **Topology** to understand few ideas used in condensed matter theory. I want to declare that I don't have any formal knowledge of knots and topology in general. So when I was reading the *chapter 2*, where he explains the rules to get **Kauffman invariant**, I got it for the worked out examples. But on page 13 while explaining the knot in single string with open boundary, he asks to think of it as a ribbon. Then he equates the twisted ribbon to $-A^{3}$ times ribbon without any twist. Link to image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZpEZv.png).

How do I get that? I couldn't get it using the rules he mentioned earlier in the chapter. Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance.